# Softkeyboad Autocorrection field overlaps EditText

Tags: android

So, when you open the keyboard and it overlaps the EditText you clicked into, the whole Screen moves up so the EditText is just above the Keyboard. This does work for me however as I said, it moves so it is just above the keyboard but above the keyboard is also this field for the autocorrection and this field overlaps the EditText. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: turn off auto-correct?

Comment: that can't be a solution!